ORA-13914 Threshold notification failed with clean sysaux/system tablespace
I have Oracle Database 19c (19.3.0.0.0). I have prepared python script to create PDBs. We use those PDBs to test our main application and then they are automatically deleted (by script of course). One time we got this error: ORA-13914 Threshold notification failed. We had SYSAUX and SYSTEM tablespaces almost full. Because of large SM/AWR object I cleaned it according to this tutorial https://oracledbwr.com/purging-cleaning-sysaux-tablespace-in-oracle/. I resized also a SYSTEM tablespace. Everything worked well again for 15 minutes. We get same errors during creating PDBs. But right now We have 556.313 MB of 2310.000 MB occupied (SYSAUX) and 934.875 MB of 2048.000 MB occupied (SYSTEM). In my opinion it should be enough space especially we had lower space earlier and everything was working well.
I cannot find any other solutions to solve my problem. What should I check again to avoid this error? I'm not database master so it would be great if you explain me like I'm newbie.

That is going to be an internal bug.  19.3 is now nearly 20 rounds of bug fixes out of date. Download the latest RU and see how you go.
